# EJB and transaction order fails

Tags: java, oracle, transactions, glassfish, ejb

There an interesting problem I have.
I have a Java Web Application with back end code.

I have to table table1 and table2. Where Table2 has Foreign Key to table1.

We using EJB.

```
table1.merge(entity);
table1.getEntityManager().flush();
table2.merge(entity2);
```

The problem that transaction commits in random order.
How to make to do it in proper order ?

Comment: The code looks somehow confusing. What kind of object are your table1 and table2 in the code example?

Comment: can you post a little bit more informations? for example the code of your entities and your EJBs? and What is table1/table2 ??